# Azure Graph API call doesn't have refresh token

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to access the graph api with my application and it is successful, however, when the token expires I there isn't a refresh token to refresh my setting and then my application stops working until I republish the app and it generates a new token.

Here is the code that I call via AJAX to get the data from the graph api:

```
[Authorize]
    public async Task<UserProfile> UserProfile()
    {

        string tenantId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(TenantIdClaimType).Value;

        // Get a token for calling the Windows Azure Active Directory Graph
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, LoginUrl, tenantId));
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(AppPrincipalId, AppKey);
        AuthenticationResult assertionCredential = authContext.AcquireToken(GraphUrl, credential);

        string authHeader = assertionCredential.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
        string requestUrl = String.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            GraphUserUrl,
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tenantId),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(User.Identity.Name));

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        UserProfile profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(responseString);
        profile.Username = User.Identity.Name.Replace("@xxx.com", "");

        return profile;
    }
```

Running through this, when I get my `assertionCredential` it has an Access token, accessTokenType, and an expiry date (1 hour from it's creation) but the refresh token is null. Do I need to edit my call to the API to get a refresh token with my call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by updating the Active Directory Authentication Library from v2.0.0 to v2.28.3.